# HTTP_REFERER not working when user comes from HTTP code 301/307

Tags: php, wordpress, http, redirect

I've written some simple code in PHP which save slug from my 301 redirect URL so I know how many visitors come from that advertisement. However, it's not working when user comes from 301/307.

Example: if user comes from 301 redirect url `example.com/example` to redirect url to `example.com/example1` now in example1 page not showing referral from this link `example.com/example`:

```
$url = example.com/example;

$data = "$url";

$j=0;   

foreach (count_chars($data, 1) as $i => $val) {
   $j=$j+$val;

}

$result = substr(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '',$j);

echo   $result;
```

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: are you using header("location:..."); to redirect?

Comment: referral link set by browser when you click on link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont rely on $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] it is purely optional for a browser to send it, and some security software blocks it in requests. Read more [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec15.html#sec15.1.3)

Comment: Silent Byte i use header("location:

Answer (score 0):

Thats a normal problem of Referer Tracking. You should use other methodes to track ads.

The most used option are Get Parameters (offer.php?ref=sitexy)